# Не понимаю отношений px и dp

Tags: android-xml

У меня есть макет figma, там размеры указаны в px, а по правилам верстки надо размеры указывать в dp/sp для текста. Объясните пожалуйста как и на что умножать чтобы мне верстать сейчас в android studio xml макет. Мне нужно указать отступы в dp чтобы приложение смотрелось красиво на разных устройствах.

Answer (score -1):

1dp обычно равняется 2px, ну или 1.5px

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).